# ES6 Sum by object property in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, ecmascript-6, reduce

I am trying to sum the unit value by date, and create a new array where there are no duplicate dates. For example, I want to calculate the total of `2015-12-04 00:01:00`. This date has occurred 2 times in the following data, its value is `5` and `6`, which is going to be:

```
[{date: '2015-12-04 00:01:00', unit: 11}, ... etc]
```

I have tried `arr = results.map(x => x.unit).reduce((a,c) => a + c)` but it only return a single value, not an array.

```js
results = [ { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 00:01:00' },
          { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 00:01:00' },
          { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 00:31:00' },
          { unit: 9, date: '2015-12-04 00:31:00' },
          { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 01:01:00' },
          { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 01:01:00' },
          { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 01:31:00' },
          { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 01:31:00' },
          { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 02:01:00' },
          { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 02:01:00' },
          { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 02:31:00' },
          { unit: 9, date: '2015-12-04 02:31:00' },
          { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 03:01:00' },
          { unit: 9, date: '2015-12-04 03:01:00' },
          { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 03:31:00' },
          { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 03:31:00' },
          { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 04:01:00' },
          { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 04:01:00' }];

arr = results.map(x => x.unit).reduce((a,c) => a + c);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: So you're trying to sum the amount of a certain date you have?

Comment: Yes, the sum of each date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reduce your data to a dictionary and then map it to an array like so

```js
results = [ { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 00:01:00' },
      { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 00:01:00' },
      { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 00:31:00' },
      { unit: 9, date: '2015-12-04 00:31:00' },
      { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 01:01:00' },
      { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 01:01:00' },
      { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 01:31:00' },
      { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 01:31:00' },
      { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 02:01:00' },
      { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 02:01:00' },
      { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 02:31:00' },
      { unit: 9, date: '2015-12-04 02:31:00' },
      { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 03:01:00' },
      { unit: 9, date: '2015-12-04 03:01:00' },
      { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 03:31:00' },
      { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 03:31:00' },
      { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 04:01:00' },
      { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 04:01:00' }]

// first make an object with {date: unit} value as such
const newResults = results.reduce((acc, item) => ({
  ...acc,
  [item.date]: (acc[item.date] || 0) + item.unit
}) , {})

console.log(newResults)
/*
{
  "2015-12-04 00:01:00": 15,
  "2015-12-04 00:31:00": 14,
  "2015-12-04 01:01:00": 15,
  "2015-12-04 01:31:00": 15,
  "2015-12-04 02:01:00": 15,
  "2015-12-04 02:31:00": 14,
  "2015-12-04 03:01:00": 14,
  "2015-12-04 03:31:00": 15,
  "2015-12-04 04:01:00": 15
}
*/

// now if you want array representation for this you can do

const finalResult = Object.keys(newResults).map(key => ({date: key, unit: newResults[key]}))

console.log(finalResult)
/*
[
  {
    "date": "2015-12-04 00:01:00",
    "unit": 15
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-12-04 00:31:00",
    "unit": 14
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-12-04 01:01:00",
    "unit": 15
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-12-04 01:31:00",
    "unit": 15
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-12-04 02:01:00",
    "unit": 15
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-12-04 02:31:00",
    "unit": 14
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-12-04 03:01:00",
    "unit": 14
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-12-04 03:31:00",
    "unit": 15
  },
  {
    "date": "2015-12-04 04:01:00",
    "unit": 15
  }
]
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the accumulator in `reduce` an object whose keys are the dates. Then you can accumulate in the `units` property.

You can use `Object.values()` to convert this back to an array.

```js
results = [ { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 00:01:00' },
          { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 00:01:00' },
          { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 00:31:00' },
          { unit: 9, date: '2015-12-04 00:31:00' },
          { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 01:01:00' },
          { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 01:01:00' },
          { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 01:31:00' },
          { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 01:31:00' },
          { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 02:01:00' },
          { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 02:01:00' },
          { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 02:31:00' },
          { unit: 9, date: '2015-12-04 02:31:00' },
          { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 03:01:00' },
          { unit: 9, date: '2015-12-04 03:01:00' },
          { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 03:31:00' },
          { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 03:31:00' },
          { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 04:01:00' },
          { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 04:01:00' }];

arr = Object.values(results.reduce((a, {
  unit,
  date
}) => (a[date] = {
  date: date,
  unit: a[date] ? a[date].unit + unit : unit
}, a), {}));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should group by date in a new element and then create a new array with the sum of units

```
let indexedDates = {};
results.forEach(result => {
   let arrayByDate = indexedDates[result.date] || [];
   arrayByDate.push(result.unit);
   indexedDates[result.date] = arrayByDate;
});
let yourExpectedResult = Object.keys(indexedDates).map(date => ({
  date,
  unit: indexedDates[date].reduce((a, b) => a +b)
}));
```

```js
let results = [ { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 00:01:00' },
      { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 00:01:00' },
      { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 00:31:00' },
      { unit: 9, date: '2015-12-04 00:31:00' },
      { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 01:01:00' },
      { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 01:01:00' },
      { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 01:31:00' },
      { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 01:31:00' },
      { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 02:01:00' },
      { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 02:01:00' },
      { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 02:31:00' },
      { unit: 9, date: '2015-12-04 02:31:00' },
      { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 03:01:00' },
      { unit: 9, date: '2015-12-04 03:01:00' },
      { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 03:31:00' },
      { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 03:31:00' },
      { unit: 10, date: '2015-12-04 04:01:00' },
      { unit: 5, date: '2015-12-04 04:01:00' }];
let indexedDates = {};
results.forEach(result => {
   let arrayByDate = indexedDates[result.date] || [];
   arrayByDate.push(result.unit);
   indexedDates[result.date] = arrayByDate;
});
let yourExpectedResult = Object.keys(indexedDates).map(date => ({
  date,
  unit: indexedDates[date].reduce((a, b) => a +b)
}));
console.log(yourExpectedResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this?

```
const x = results.reduce((accu, r) => {
    const { unit, date } = r;
    accu[date] = accu[date] || { unit: 0, date };
    accu[date].unit += unit;
    return accu;
}, {});
const yourNeed = Object.values(x);
```